# Resetting Advertising ID on iPad does not work?

Tags: ipad, settings

I'm really *really* sick and tired of these websites showing me ads '*in my interest*'. So I did some research and 99% of the answers from nearly *20* sources say to reset advertising ID and turn on *limit ad tracking*.

I do this and there is **no change**. I clear cookies, passwords, auto fill, cache, and browsing history. Every piece of browsing data has been terminated (including uninstalling/reinstalling browsers AND restarting iPad) (RIP saved passwords, your cause went to nothing)

No matter how many times I do this "*simple* and **ONLY** fix" available within **6** pages of web searching, it fails to un-personalize ads.
I tried getting the services that were tracking me to clear the data they have on me, but no avail.

Conclusion: I'm at a dead end with no leads.

I've been at this for hours.
Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? And if I hear "*click reset advertisement ID and check limit ad tracking*" (without extra instructions) one more forsaken time, **I *will* break**.

I'm running **IOS 10.3.3** ipad(*mk9p2ll/a*).
I don't plan on updating unless my current version is *PRECISELY* the issue here.

If I were to try and think why it's not working, I'd figure this much:

Maybe it's not my browser or ad id (I think this because the same exact trash is happening on my pc) (Maybe my IP is being used for ad tracking?)

Or maybe I'm just an idiot wasting everyone's time because he doesn't know anything else than "*clear browser data*" and "*click reset ads*" that google displays for a good 6 pages.

Comment: Hey, Welcome to Apple.SE! Isn't the advertiser ID only for Apple using your data for ads or apps in App Store? More info on the website version is on http://optout.networkadvertising.org/?c=1 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205223 explains what is under Apple's control.

> Ads that are delivered by Apple’s advertising platform may appear in the App Store on iOS, Apple News, and Stocks.

Other websites use a lot of other methods to collect advertising data

> including browser cookies, mobile advertising identifiers as well as other non-cookie technologies *

Although Safari limits tracking by "Intelligent Tracking Prevention", "Fingerprinting defence" etc., it is not fully preventable against the trackers.

What you can try is to install ad and tracker blockers. You might want to look into their permission to read and transfer content.

Also, opt-out of Google Adsense can reduce the "Behavioural" Advertising. You'll still see ads, just less relevant. 
<sub>https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/142293?hl=en</sub>

*<sup>From  http://optout.networkadvertising.org/?c=1</sup>